# Replace \n with blank in a file

Tags: shell, text-processing

I want to replace `\n` with blank

Input `file1`

```
A\n
D\n
```

Output `file2`  I want

```
A       
D
```

I tried below commands but not able to replace.

```
cat OUT | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace all newlines in the file with spaces, turning the entire file into one long, unterminated line? Or do you mean than your file contains backslash (``\``) characters, and, when one of them is immediately followed by an `n`, you want to replace that _pair of characters_ with a space? ... ... ... ... ... ... P.S. Why is your input file called `OUT`?

Comment: The other answers make things clear, but also in general, `tr` is for *character replacement*. Not for string replacement. Also, the question is confusing, I first assumed that you wanted to replace the newlines with spaces, not literal `\n` with an empty string. Do you want to only do this substitution at the end of the line or anywhere?

Comment: are you just trying to convert DOS/Windows file to Unix files?

Comment: how about this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script]

Answer (score 6):

Many good answers, I'll add the sed way

```
 sed 's#\\n##g' file1 >  file2
```

Comment: In `awk` you'd do something like: `awk '{ gsub(/\\n/,"") }1' file`  Also quite funny you use hashes `#` as substitution delimiters.

Comment: so far you have the only correct answer. +1. if i nitpick a bit, I'd add a `$` after the n, if you only want to delete the \n that are at the *end* of each line

Comment: @val0x00ff - I use #'s to avoid picket fence looking sed commands when having to escape complexer strings. And thanks for the awk example, i'm trying to get more mileage out of it besides the usual 'default' commands.
- olivier-dulac Good remark, i will add the $ anchor in the anser

Comment: hmmm, adding the $ anchor makes it miss the last occurance.
doing $* does work but looks a bit too greedy...

Comment: with awk there are probably a few dozen ways to do this

Answer (score 2):

An alternate would be to take only the first character using `cut`:

```
$ cut -c1 < input_file 
A
D
```

Answer (score 2):

From post:

> I tried below commands but not able to replace please do needful.
>
> ```
> cat OUT | tr '\n' ' '
> ```

---

The problem with with above command is : **`tr` understands `\n` as "new line character"**

#### From [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
$ man tr | grep Interpreted -A 18
       SETs are specified as strings of characters.  Most represent themselves.  Interpreted sequences are:

       \NNN   character with octal value NNN (1 to 3 octal digits)

       \\     backslash

       \a     audible BEL

       \b     backspace

       \f     form feed

       \n     new line

       \r     return

       \t     horizontal tab

       \v     vertical tab
```

So to specify `\n` you need to specify [backslash][n] i.e **`\\n`** (see specification listed above). Thus Use the following command:

```
tr -s '\\n' ' '
```

To `cat` `file1` and redirect(`>`) to `file2` Use:

```
cat file1 | tr -s '\\n' ' ' > file2
```

---

**But the problem with using `tr` is that it translates EVERY `\` and `n` to space**.

So, I recommend to use **`sed`** as follows:

Command for `sed` substitution (`sed 's/old-string/new-string/g' in > out`) :

```
sed 's/\\n/ /g' file1 > file2
```

Here only `\n` (whole word) will be converted into space

Comment: Your `tr` solution will destroy every `\ ` and `n` in the file, just like [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189205/replace-n-with-blank-in-a-file/189208#189208).

Comment: @joeytwiddle oh! you are right; I revised answer by specifying problem with `tr` and recommending `sed`!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the two characters `\` and `n` at the end of every line with a space, use

```
sed 's/\\n$/ /' < file1
```

Note that your example output has several spaces after `A` and a single space after `D`, but the above command always places a single space.

Comment: This would be a good answer if the closing `'` wasn't missing!

Comment: @joeytwiddle thx, fixed it!

Comment: We still don't know if the OP wants a space or an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tr`

`tr -d '\\n' < input_file > output_file`

Comment: This will clobber _every_ ``\`` and _every_ `n` -- probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: Oh, It seems I've been missing something!  Thanks for pointing it out. I'm just leaving the answer here so other will know how to NOT do it.

Answer (score -1):

you could try a trick!

First get rid of 'n' at the end of the file:

```
cat "your_file.txt" | sed -e 's/\<n\>//g' > "new_file.txt"
```

then get rid of the "\" character:

```
cat "new_file.txt" | tr -s "\\" " " > "final_file.txt"
```

and you're going to have the output without the \n.

Comment: No need for `cat` here. `sed` will accept input files as arguments (eg. `sed EXPR file`), and an input redirection could be used for `tr` (eg. `tr a b < file`).

Comment: This defeats the purpose of having full regular expression capabilities at your disposal. Why use `sed` and *not* remove the entire string that's a problem? Secondly, this doesn't even do what you want. `tr` will replace all occurences of `\` in the line with a space.  Also your `sed` command doesn't check if `n` is at the end of the line, and needlessly does a *global* replacement. Why not just
`sed 's/\\n$//' input.txt > output.txt` (or remove "$" if `\n` can happen anywhere).